# Compiling ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, compilation, mingw32

I'm compiling ASP.NET code for the first time ever and I'm stumped.

I downloaded MINGW-Get and just finished installing it. The client gave me the source code and I found a file called RSConfig.exe.

So I assumed that was the config file, ran it, and then tried "make" but got the error

```
No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop
```

Any idea what I'm supposed to do? I don't see anything that would resemble a makefile in the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what environment are you working in? Unix, windows? Are you working within Visual Studio? If so what version?

Comment: I'm in Windows, and all I've been using is MinGW commands, I haven't done anything in Visual Studio. Someone just sent me the code and asked me to compile it.

It's the first time I've done this, so I'm completely lost...and I did research online and couldn't find anything. Sorry if this seems too vague, not sure what else to specify

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favour and install Visual Studio Express:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

It makes development easier and fast

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to get familiar with the background concepts around asp.net and it's defacto development environment Visual Studio (there are many versions of visual studio).

As Andrei recommends, using Visual Studio Express is a good free way of getting started. The version most suited for web development is Visual Web Developer Express.

Attempting to compile .net code from a toolset such as MinGW isn't a typical route for using asp.net, however I've not used MinGW before and not sure it's possible to compile .net code from it.... Although it is perfectly possible to compile .net code from the command line (using the .net framework sdk) , I certainly wouldn't recommend it if you are getting started.

I'm going to make a guess that it is an ASP.net web forms project, it being the most prolific asp.net project type at the moment.

This official asp.net site http://www.asp.net/web-forms will guide you through what web forms are and how to get the development environment setup. Having this sort of background will aid you in solving your particular situation.

Comment: yes, it is best to concentrate on programming than making all those build files